# performance difference between building an ionic 4 app using react vs angular

Tags: reactjs, performance, vue.js, ionic4

I have been using ionic 3 to build mobile applications. With the release of **ionic 4** where you can use react or vue or angular, What is the performance difference building an ionic 4 application using **react** vs **angular** vs **vue**.

Answer (score 1):

It depends for you.If you are good command in angular then u should go for it.React and Vue it will take time to stable and not more tutorials and blogs.

I think you should go with angular

Answer (score 1):

Well, this depends on you. There is nothing the three of them can't do. But there are some important factors to consider as well. I will like to compare React and Vue for instance.

1. React is developed and maintained by facebook developers, for this reason, it has a great and large community of developers working on it. While Vue is developed by an individual, and its community is just growing.
2. React has more open jobs opportunities than Vue

   3. React will enhance your JavaScript ability more than Vue, though Vue is very easy and fun to learn.

Here are some few links to help you decide: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/i-created-the-exact-same-app-in-react-and-vue-here-are-the-differences-e9a1ae8077fd

https://hackernoon.com/angular-vs-react-vs-vue-which-is-the-best-choice-for-2019-16ce0deb3847